# Ruby: Getting salesforce oauth_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

I have `client_id` and `client_secret` but to authenticate, i need `oauth_token`. How do I get this token using Ruby on Rails? I tried with few option but could not work out.

Gem used : databasedotcom

I tried the below option but it is not responding
https://gist.github.com/undees/300175

```
require 'oauth'

consumer_key    = '...' # from SalesForce
consumer_secret = '...' # from SalesForce

oauth_options = {
:site               => 'https://login.salesforce.com',
:scheme             => :body,
:request_token_path => '/_nc_external/system/security/oauth/RequestTokenHandler',
:authorize_path     => '/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp',
:access_token_path  => '/_nc_external/system/security/oauth/AccessTokenHandler',
}
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new consumer_key, consumer_secret, oauth_options
# consumer.http.set_debug_output STDERR # if you're curious 
request       = consumer.get_request_token
authorize_url = request.authorize_url :oauth_consumer_key => consumer_key 
puts "Go to #{authorize_url} in your browser, then enter the verification code:"
verification_code = gets.strip 
access = request.get_access_token :oauth_verifier => verification_code

puts "Access Token:  " + access.token
puts "Access Secret: " + access.secret
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you have tried and what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: databasedotcom-oAuth2 gem worked for me. It takes client key and secret and interact with salesforce. Detail is given in here.
Click Here http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_databasedotcom-oauth2_Gem